# Migrating youtube id from a csv file

Tags: files, migrations

I have a content type called video with two fields, title and youtube id. Im migrating content to the site using csv files however every time I migrate the youtube id field is always empty.

The field type for the id is Youtube VideoID.

```
<?php

class VideoMigration extends Migration {
  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->description = t('Import videos from CSV file.');
    $this->dependencies = array();
    $this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName,
      array(
        'nid' => array(
          'type' => 'int',
          'not null' => true,
        ),
      ),
      MigrateDestinationNode::getKeySchema()
    );
    $this->source = new MigrateSourceCSV(drupal_get_path('module', 'deploy_content') . '/import/video/csv/video.csv', $this->csvcolumns(), array('header_rows' => 1));
    $this->destination = new MigrateDestinationNode('video', array('text_format' => 'full_html'));
    $this->addFieldMapping('nid', 'nid');
    $this->addFieldMapping('is_new')
         ->defaultValue(TRUE);
    $this->addFieldMapping('title', 'title');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_video_embed_code', 'youtube');
  }

  function csvcolumns() {
    $columns[0] = array('nid', 'NID');
    $columns[1] = array('title', 'Title');
    $columns[2] = array('youtube', 'YouTube');
    return $columns;
  }
}
```

Any ideas why this could be happening?